# Python - How to NOT, OR and use other logical operators on two binary numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, logic

I have two arrays which I use to denote whether an element is present or not, (1 = True or present and 0 = not present). Both are the same size and element one in array one corresponds to the same element in array 2.  I need to do some logic calculations on the two numpy binary arrays as listed below:

```
[0,0,0,0,1,1,0]   Array 1
[0,0,0,0,1,0,1]   Array 2
```

I have AND working which gives me this:

```
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0]   Array after AND operation
```

Which tells me where for each element it is the same or present in both arrays.

What I need is to output an array where there is a 1 in array 1 but not in array 2 (A1 & ! A2). Such as:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
```

Another where There is not a 1 in Array 1 but there is a 1 in Array 2 (! A1 &A2), Such as:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

and where there is not a 1 in either Aray 1 or Array 2 (! A1 & ! A2)

```
[1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

Hope that makes sense, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you have boolean arrays, you can use the ordinary bitwise operators `~` (not), `|` (or), `&` (and). They also work with ordinary integer arrays of course, but then `~0` gives -1, for example.

To create a boolean array, give the argument `dtype=bool` to `np.array` (or another Numpy function that returns arrays). Get a cast copy of an existing array by using `ndarray.astype(bool)`.

Answer (score 1):

For logical not you can use:

```
not_array = np.logical_not(arr) + [0 for i in xrange(len(arr))]
```

and after that you can use the AND operation which you state you have figured out already.

P.S: np is numpy

Comment: So this would give me the NOT for one single array (Array1) and then you are suggesting that I then AND that with Array 2?

Comment: Yes, and you can use it to get the NOT for array 2 also.

Answer (score 0):

```
#What I need is to output an array where there is a 1 in array 1 but not in array 2 (A1 & ! A2)
a*(a-b)
Out[626]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])

#Another where There is not a 1 in Array 1 but there is a 1 in Array 2 (! A1 &A2)
b*(b-a)
Out[648]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

#and where there is not a 1 in either Aray 1 or Array 2 (! A1 & ! A2)
1-(a|b)
Out[639]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```